# Recursion and basecase in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have a function which I can not get to run correctly and I cant figure out why. I think it may have to do with the base case.

This is what I have:

```
recursion(Start, [Tail|Tails], [Alpha|Alphas], Beta, [X|Xs]):-
  third(Start, Alpha, S),
  second(S,Beta,Tail,X),
  recursion(Start, Tails, Alphas, Beta,Xs).
recursion([],[],[],_,[]).
```

I know that the second function works correctly but when I run this:

```
recursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, X).
```

I get:

```
T Call: (6) recursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, _G3980)
T Fail: (6) recursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, _G3980)
false.
```

My other predicates can be found:

```
second(A,B,_,1) :- A > B.
second(A,B,C,C) :- A == B.
second(A,B,_,-1) :- A < B.

third([A|As], [B|Bs], X) :-
    third(As, Bs, Z),
    X is Z + A* B.
third([],[],0).
```

UPDATE:

Start and Tail will both be the exact same list entered into the predicate. Thats why in the example they are both [1,2]. When I change my base case to `recursion(_,[],[],_,[]).` I get:

```
98 ?- recursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, X).
T Call: (6) recursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, _G1632)
T Redo: (6) recursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, _G1632)
T Fail: (6) recursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, _G1632)
false.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It comes out as false

Comment: Yes, your predicate query (it's not a function) fails and yields false. What result are you expecting?

Comment: It is supposed to return a list. second returns 1, -1 or C for the list. Third returns a value to second which is then compared.

Comment: I can see what `second` does. What is `recursion` supposed to do? I can see that it returns a list, but under what conditions? A list of what?

Comment: recursion is the one that is supposed to create the list that is outputted. This may look like [1,-1] for example.

Comment: One problem is that your recursion base case assumes that the first argument reduces to `[]`. However, you are always passing `Start` as the first argument; it never reduces. Perhaps your base case should be `recursion(_, [], [], _, [])`? That's the answer @dasblinkenlight gave. Did you consider his suggestion?

Comment: One thing is that Start and Tail will both be the thing. And yes, when I do that I get a redo in trace.

Comment: *...Start and Tail will both be the thing* I have no idea what that means. If you correct your base case, as @dasblinkenlight answered, you will get `[1, 1]` as a solution. If you are then having a different problem, you need to describe it clearly in another post.

Comment: When I run your code with the corrected base case, I get `[1,1]` as an answer. If you're just getting `false`, that means the code you're running doesn't match the code you are showing in your problem statement. Please check to make sure that they are the same.

Comment: I rewrote my code and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Your base case is not getting accessed because `Start` is passed to `recursion` unchanged. Therefore, it will never unify with the empty list, meaning that only the first clause of `recursion` will be used.

It does not look like `Start` is being used in your function, so you might either ignore it, like that

```
recursion(_, [],[],_,[]).
```

or remove it altogether, like this:

```
recursion([Tail|Tails], [Alpha|Alphas], Beta, [X|Xs]):-
  second(5,Beta,Tail,X),
  recursion(Tails, Alphas, Beta,Xs).
recursion([],[],_,[]).
```

Comment: Thank you. I am now getting this:T Call: (6) nextStateRecursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, _G896)
 T Redo: (6) nextStateRecursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, _G896)
 T Fail: (6) nextStateRecursion([1, 2], [1, 2], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 0, _G896)
false.

Comment: @user081608 This works perfectly on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/mDAEN2)). Check your `second/4` rules to see what's going on - they need to provide a value of `X`, so that it could be placed into `[X|Xs]` on the way up.

Comment: Ill add my second function above.

Comment: Can you replace the middle clause of second wit second(A,A,C,C).

Comment: I changed my uptop question with more info and where start comes from.

Comment: @user081608 Again, your code worked fine on ideone ([new link](http://ideone.com/xYEnjY)).